# Variable declared within hive context is not visible outside

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The below issue occurs only in eclipse and not in spark-shell.

```
val dt=hc.sql(s"select max(filedt) as audit_dt,cast('$file_dt' as date) as curr_dt from cortex_dev.audit where filename='XPO Click'")
       if (dt.filter($"audit_dt" > $"curr_dt").count == 0) 
       {...}
```

Here, eclipse complains for $"audit_dt" and $"curr_dt" saying,

```
Value $ is not a member of StringContext
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I had to add this after declaring 'val hc' -

```
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
import hc.implicits._
```